# How to test external app run correctly?

Tags: android, android-espresso

The target is to test external app run intent. When this test case passed all of the next test cases failed because the external app doesn't closed after test case finished. My test is looks like:

```
public class MarketIntentCase {

private ActivityTestRule<SomeActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(SomeActivity.class, true, false);   

@Rule
public RuleChain ruleChain = RuleChain.emptyRuleChain()
        .around(activityTestRule); 

    @Before
    public void launchActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        activityTestRule.launchActivity(intent);
    }

public void shouldShowGooglePlay() {
        Intents.init();
        Intents.intended(hasData(Uri.parse(Constants.MARKET_URL)));
        Intents.intended(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW));
        Intents.release();
    }
}
```

Please, give me advice how to test such behavior correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to kill the Activity (external or app under test) while running Espresso test. Maybe if you combine Espresso and UI automator (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html) it should works, source: http://alexzh.com/tutorials/android-testing-espresso-uiautomator-together/